# Splitting train and test set with labels in sklearn?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scikit-learn

I have an augmented dataset in which I have a list `label` to group original data and their augmentations. Is there a method in `sklearn` like [`train_test_split()`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) but guarantees the same label would not appear in both subsets? A similar method I can think of is [`LabelKFold()`](http://vighneshbirodkar.github.io/scikit-learn.github.io/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.LabelKFold.html).

For example, I have `x = [[1,1], [2,2], [3,3], [4,4], [5,5], [6,6]]`, `y = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]`, `label = [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2]`.

I want `[1,1]` and `[2,2]` (who have the same label) to be split into the same subset.

Comment: Same for [3,3], [4,4] ?

Comment: @seralouk Yes, same as [5,5] and [6,6]

Comment: see my answer and let me know if this works for you

Answer (score 2):

You can use `GroupKFold` to do this.  Here's how you would do a single 66/33 split.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GroupKFold

gkf = GroupKFold(n_splits=3)
train, test = next(gkf.split(X, y, groups=label))
X_train = X[train]
y_train = y[train]
X_test = X[test]
y_test = y[test]
```

Comment: For future reference, `n_splits=3` is arbitrary, since we're interested in getting just a single fold.